# Make a String text Bold in Java Android

Tags: java, android, string, text

I want to make **Habit Number**: bold , I tried the HTML tag but it didn't work.
I did some research but couldn't find any. Hope someone is able to help me. Thanks!

```
String habitnumber = "Habit Number: " + String.valueOf(habitcounter);
String Title = habit.getTitle();
String description = habit.getDescription();


//Set text for the row
                tv.setText(habitnumber+ "\n" + Title + " \n" + description + "\n --------------------");
```

Comment: How are you eventually displaying it on screen?  That makes a big difference

Comment: @GabeSechan edited my question, see it now

Comment: You need to set it in a spannable with a bold style.  Alternatively, you can add the bold html tags then use Html.fromHtml to get a string with spannables formed from the html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
I tried the HTML tag but it didn't work
```

I think that you didnt wrap your string to `Html.fromHtml`

**solution:**

You can do it with HTML using html tag for bold: `<b>`

```
 String habitnumber = "<b>" + "Habit Number: " + "</b> " + String.valueOf(habitcounter);
 tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(habitnumber ));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: The problem with this is it makes the entire textview bold.  Which may not be what he wants.

Comment: so maybe textview in textview? whats problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Like Gabe mentioned, try using the use Html.fromHtml or use spannable.
Check this out: [Selecting, Highlighting, or Styling Portions of Text](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext)

You could basically use html tags in your string resource like:

```
<resource>
<string id="@+id/styled_welcome_message"><b>your text</b></string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the XML file, inside the textview

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```